# Connection Failing to Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-network

Here is how I run my docker container -

```
docker run --name docker-test-server -p 5000:5000 -p 4444:4444
```

Container OS - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Now since I have mapped 4444 of container to that of machine, I try to connect -

```
root@localhost:/var/repo# nc -vz 127.0.0.1 4444
Connection to 127.0.0.1 4444 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Now I enter the shell -

```
docker exec -it docker-test-server /bin/bash
```

Successfully entering, I try to get the IP address of the machine.

```
root@ec919687cda8:/# ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:11:00:09
          inet addr:172.17.0.9  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2227 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2199 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:166686 (166.6 KB)  TX bytes:121473 (121.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Now I come out of the container, and try to connect to the container from the machine where the container is running by providing the IP address of container found in ifconfig -

```
nc -vz 172.17.0.9 4444
nc: connect to 172.17.0.9 port 4444 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Could someone, please explain me

1. why am I unable to connect to the machine?
2. What can I do to connect to the machine?

I am running a bare container that just installs ubuntu 14.04 and exposes 2 ports. Nothing fancy.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have 2 containers, docker-test-server and docker-pub-server? Can you post a `docker port` of them?

Comment: What is your host? What OS? And what version of docker are you using?

Comment: @VonC host OS - ubuntu 14.04 on google cloud. Docker version 1.10.1, build 9e83765

Comment: @user2915097 - No, I don't have two containers. There is just docker-test-server. 

`docker port docker-test-server
4444/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:4444
5000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:5000`

Comment: You should not need to enter the container, when you map a port, you should access it from your host, with a browser at http://localhost:5000 or such

Comment: Please re-read the question once again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either disable the firewall or add port to your ubuntu firewall by using **sudo ufw disable** or **sudo ufw**

I was also facing the same issue but instead of connection refused, I got timeout.